# Adding number in two dimensional table

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got for example two dimensional table 3x2 where all element have got 4x minus :"----". If I write in program for example 32. The first number tells us what number it is and second how many number is in row.

it will make my table like this (32):

```
---- ----      33-- ----
---- ----   -> ---- ----
---- ----      ---- ----
```

Then when we write another one (53): it will check table [0][0] if it is empty and if it is not it will be checked table [1][0]  and   table [0][1] if both are empty it will select table with lower number in this case table [0][1].

```
33-- ----      33-- 555-
---- ----   -> ---- ----
---- ----      ---- ----
```

there we can put other numbers:

```
33-- 555-      33-- 555-
---- ----   -> 444- 22--
---- ----      333- 222-
```

we insert number in empty place- when all place is not empty we insert number there where
is more "-" symbols - we take number 42 and in 33-- change it on 3344

```
33-- 555-      3344 555-
444- 22--   -> 444- 22--
333- 222-      333- 222-
```

if we want insert more number in place where is not enough "-"- program ends

I started like this:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Skladisce2
{
    public static int dolzina;
    public static int sirina;
    public static int enote;
    public static int tabela[][][];
        ////////////////////////////////////
        //// PREGLED VRSTIC
        ////////////////////////////////////

    public static boolean Vstavi(int barva, int visina) {
                int pozdolzina = 0;
                int pozsirina = 0;
                int najbolProsto = 0;
                    for(int j=0; j<dolzina; j++) {
                        for(int i=0; i<sirina; i++) {
                            int prosto=0;
                            for(int k=0;k<enote;k++) {
                                if( tabela[j][i][k]==0){
                                prosto++;


                                }
                                if( prosto>najbolProsto ) {
                                pozdolzina = i;
                                pozsirina = j;
                                najbolProsto = prosto;

                                for (int l=enote-najbolProsto; ((l<enote) &&(visina>0));  l++) {
                                    tabela[pozdolzina][pozsirina][l] = barva;


                                    visina--;}
                                    continue;


                }k++;

                            }
                        }

                    }   

                return true;
        }   

        /////////////////////////////////////
        ////   IZPIS TABELE
       //////////////////////////////////////
        public static void Izpis() {
            for (int i=0; i<dolzina; i++){
                for (int j=0; j<sirina; j++){
                    for (int k=0; k<enote; k++) {
                        if(tabela[i][j][k] == 0) {
                            System.out.print("-");
                            }
                        else{
                            System.out.print(tabela[i][j][k]);
                            }
                    }
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }

    public static void main (String[] args) {   

        Scanner vnos_stevila = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Insert dimension: ");
        int vnos = vnos_stevila.nextInt();

        // int vnos razdeli na podenote - prva številka je dolžina, druga širina in tretja enota
        dolzina = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(vnos).substring(0,1));
        sirina = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(vnos).substring(1,2));
        enote = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(vnos).substring(2,3));

        // izpis tabele s črtami
        tabela= new int[dolzina][sirina][enote];

            // izriše črtice
            Izpis();



          // VPIS SODOV
         while (true){
            System.out.print("Insert color and number");
            int sod = vnos_stevila.nextInt();
            int dolzinaIzpisa =  (int)(Math.log10(sod)+1);



            int barva = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(sod).substring(0,1));
            int visina = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(sod).substring(1,2));

            Vstavi(barva,visina);   

            Izpis();
            }}
}
```

but when I insert number 32 it write:

```
33-- 33--     
33-- 33--   
33-- 33--
```

How can I make program where will check the lowest table and insert number?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a matter of searching for the best free slot and inserting there. You may also find it easier to think of what you have as a three dimensional array, not a 2 dimensional one.

```
import java.io.Console;


public class ArrayDemo {
private final int sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ;
private final int[][][] values;

public ArrayDemo() {
    this(2,3,4);
}

public ArrayDemo(int x, int y, int z) {
    values = new int[x][y][z];
    sizeX = x;
    sizeY = y;
    sizeZ = z;

    for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<y;j++) {
            for(int k=0;k<z;k++) {
                values[i][j][k]=-1;
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean insert(int value, int count) {
    // find first slot with enough room
    int posX = -1;
    int posY = -1;
    int bestFree = 0;

    // locate largest available slot
    for(int j=0;j<sizeY;j++) {
        for(int i=0;i<sizeX;i++) {
            int free=0;
            for(int k=0;k<sizeZ;k++) {
                if( values[i][j][k]==-1 ) free++;
            }
            if( free>bestFree ) {
                posX = i;
                posY = j;
                bestFree = free;
            }
        }
    }

    // did we find a slot?
    if( bestFree<count ) return false;

    // found slot, insert data
    for(int k=sizeZ-bestFree;(k<sizeZ) && (count>0);k++) {
        values[posX][posY][k] = value;
        count--;
    }
    return true;
}


public String toString() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for(int j=0;j<sizeY;j++) {
        for(int i=0;i<sizeX;i++) {
            if( i>0 ) buf.append(' ');
            for(int k=0;k<sizeZ;k++) {
                if( values[i][j][k]==-1 ) {
                    buf.append('-');
                } else {
                    buf.append(Character.forDigit(values[i][j][k], 36));
                }
            }
        }
        buf.append('\n');
    }
    return buf.toString();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayDemo array = new ArrayDemo();
    Console cons = System.console();
    while( true ) {
        String in = cons.readLine();
        in = in.trim();
        if( in.length() != 2 ) {
            cons.printf("Please supply two digits: value and number\n");
            continue;
        }
        int inputVal = Character.digit(in.charAt(0),36); 
        int inputNum = Character.digit(in.charAt(1),36);
        if( inputVal==-1 || inputNum==-1 ) {
            cons.printf("Please supply two digits: value and number\n");
            continue;
        }

        if( array.insert(inputVal,inputNum) ) {
            cons.printf("Data inserted OK\n%s\n", array.toString());
        } else {
            cons.printf("Data could not be inserted. Finished. Final array is:\n\n%s\n",array.toString());
            return;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i got problem when i change it in 3*3 table- becouse it must go to checked diagonal where is empty place thanks